# Cannot use expression in where clause

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I want to implement a server-side filtering of DataTable. Here is the service method for retrieving the list :

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> list(int start, int length, String search, int triIdx, String ordreTri) {

        String hql = "from User ";

        if (!search.equals("") && search != null) {

            hql = hql.concat(" where ");

            if (NumberUtils.isNumber(search))
                hql = hql.concat(" salary ");
            else
                hql = hql.concat(" lower(username) ");

            hql = hql.concat(" like lower('%:critere%') ");

        }

        if (ordreTri.equals("asc")) {
            switch (triIdx) {
                case 0:
                    hql = hql.concat(" order by username ");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    hql = hql.concat(" order by email ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    hql = hql.concat(" order by salary ");
                    break;
                default:
                    hql = hql.concat(" order by username ");
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (triIdx) {
            case 0:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by username desc");
                break;
            case 1:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by email desc");
                break;
            case 2:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by salary desc");
                break;
            default:
                hql = hql.concat(" order by username desc");
                break;
            }
        }

        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        query = query.setParameter("critere",search);
        query = query.setFirstResult(start);
        query = query.setMaxResults(length);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();
        return listUser;
    }
```

At runtime I get a dataTable alert error about data. So what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: There is no critera. Your string is escaped hence the query is executed as is and doesn't contain criteria named `critere`. Remove the escaping and prefix/suffix your criteria with `%` before setting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hql.concat(" like lower('%:critere%') ")
```

should be rewrittent to :

```
hql.concat(" like :critere ")
query = query.setParameter("critere", "%" + search.toLowerCase(Locale. ....) + "%");
```